# change date format excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have the following date in excel "5/2/2020", I would like to obtain "5/Feb/2020", but unfortunately I am getting "May/2/2020".

Also tried to change the format of the cells , but excel still interprets that the first number is the month.

How do I tell Excel that the month is in the second position ?

Comment: Is the value of 5/2/2020 a string or a date? If you add 1 to it, does it give you 6/2/2020, 5/3/2020 or `#VALUE!`?

Comment: You could try right click cell then Format Cells -> Custum and Type write : d/mm/yyyy

Comment: *How do I tell Excel that the month is in the second position?* You have to tell that to Excel **at the time you import the date** from it's source. Unless Excel is told differently at that time, it will parse the date according to your Windows Regional short date settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
If 5/2/2020 is in cell E5 then:

```
=VALUE(TEXT(E5,"d/mm/yyyy"))
```

and then custom number format this cell to d/mmm/yyyy

will yield 5/Feb/2020

Comment: After re-testing this formula, does not work for =VALUE(TEXT("13/01/2021","d/mm/yyyy")), gives an error. It works when in the first position are numbers <=12

Comment: I added another answer using a custom VBA function. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a new method tested with the following dates 5/2/2020, 22/2/2020, 22/12/2020, 12/2/2020.

This function splits the date numbers into 3 parts and places them into an array using the "/" as the split delimiter. It then reassembles the 3 parts in the order you wanted.

**Step 1**: Add the following Custom Function to a VBA Module:

```
Function Dates(Cell As Variant)
'Forces recalculation when call values are changed
 Application.Volatile

  Dim DateString As String
  Dim DateArray() As String

  DateString = Cell
  DateArray = Split(DateString, "/")
  Dates = DateArray(1) & "/" & DateArray(0) & "/" & DateArray(2)

End Function
```

**Step 2**: For example, enter the date you want to convert in Cell A1 (i.e. 5/2/2020).

**Step 3**: Put the function formula =VALUE(Dates(A1)) in Cell B1.

**Step 4**: Apply the custom number format to Cell B1: d/mmm/yyyy and the result will be 5/Feb/2020.

If you want to change the number format to mmm/dd/yyyy, then the result will be Feb/05/2020.

Note: the =VALUE(Dates(A1)) formula will work anywhere on the spreadsheet. All you have to do is change the cell reference A1 to another cell reference. You can also use the formula many times on the same spreadsheet.

Sammy